# i need to know how to scrape two things together

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

```
   import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#url = input("Url : ")
url = "https://www.boohoo.com/womens/tops/t-shirts-vests?cat=t-shirts-vests"
r = requests.get(url)
page = r.content
if r.status_code == 200:
    print("succeed!")
elif r.status_code == 403:
    print("not succeed!")
# add soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
# test
print(soup.h2.string)
# product_type
product_type = soup.h2.string

# for to get information about name and price!
for divs in soup.find_all("a",class_="name-link js-canonical-link"):
    print(divs.get_text().strip())
input("Click any key to exit!")
```

help me output this tag behind the name product
class price is spam product-sales-price

Answer (score 0):

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.boohoo.com/womens/tops/t-shirts-vests?cat=t-shirts-vests"
r = requests.get(url)

if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    for li in soup.select(".grid-tile"):
        item_title = li.select(".name-link.js-canonical-link")[0].text
        item_price_discount = li.select(".product-sales-price")
        item_price = li.select(".product-standard-price")

        if item_price_discount:
            item_price = item_price_discount[0].text
        else:
            item_price = item_price[0].text

        print(f'Item Title: {item_title}\nItem Price: {item_price}')
```

this code will give you the item title and item price (only for the site you provided)